# Why process that terminated by script from PowerCli stuck in "suspended" mode

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

When I run a script trough PowerCLI after connecting to a VM, I get a strange behavior of some processes, I'm using the "**Invoke-VMScript**" command that is running an EXE file (compiled in .Net 4.5) that looks for running process and try to kill them.

For some reason some process doesn't get closed, and stuck in "**Suspended**" mode. When they stuck in this mode even if I tried to remove them from the task manager I get an error "The operation could not be complete, Access is denies."

I'm logged in with the **Administrator** user

The powershell script that I'm using is:

```
        $executeCommand = "call D:\myCleaningProcess.exe $param1";
        Invoke-VMScript -VM $vmName -GuestUser $vmUser -GuestPassword $vmPass -ScriptText $executeCommand
```

*When running manually the file "EXE" it's works as expected and the process get killed.

Anyone know why I get this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the *-ScriptType Bat* parameter when calling EXEs in this manner. See example 3 for reference: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FInvoke-VMScript.html